# How to configure the target binary as 32bit with jenkins CMake plugin

Tags: c++, jenkins, cmake, compilation

this is actually an [continuation of my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892333/how-to-use-jenkins-to-build-32-bit-and-64-bit-program-and-sealed-in-one-package) , how to build 32&64 at same time with jenkins from svn , @fabian  gave an very helpful answer ,it almost solves my problem, but unfortunately there is still one more pain, as I want to use cmake plugin.

[image]

now I can build the 64bit version , just input --config Release argument and src and build path is sufficient now .

But now choked on how to build 32bit version , I try to  fill Script Generator field with Visual Studio 16 2019 -A 32 ,but doesn't work , I think maybe I should provide an argument ,but have no clue with the format&details of the argument...

And I have searched on the web a while ,but haven't found an answer . Maybe  I could choose  windows batch command , with the command type -G """ "Visual Studio ..." -A 32 ...""" ,but I am so close , and kind outraged why this also could become a problem ( and  I am a toddler for  CMake indeed ....)

Comment: yes ,I know this question maybe is annoying , but I really have done the research , and I am really curious & frustrated why  I can't figure it out myself or searched answer from web

Comment: "-A 32" is not correct. [This page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Visual%20Studio%2016%202019.html) lists the valid -G and -A combinations for VS2019. Pay attention to the quotes, they are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

finally , I have figured out the solution , in the advanced setting part , in the other cmake argument field , fill -A 32    will solve this . I fell it seems a naive question ,but hope this could help other people , as I found that Q&A  kind content about jenkins &cmake is not very much.....

Comment: ps: in my windows environment , I input -A Win32